# .NET Color Selector comboBox not populating

Tags: c#, colors, combobox, selector

I found some code that creates an owner-drawn `comboBox` color selector. However, it was written for VS 2005 and I'm using VS 2013.

There's not much to the code but when I run it, the `comboBox` does not populate at all.

Can someone tell me what I need to modify to get it to work in VS 2013 C#?

```
private void cmbboxClr_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Rectangle rect = e.Bounds;
    if (e.Index >= 0)
    {
        string n = ((ComboBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString();
        Font f = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular);
        Color c = Color.FromName(n);
        Brush b = new SolidBrush(c);
        g.DrawString(n, f, Brushes.Black, rect.X, rect.Top);
        g.FillRectangle(b, rect.X + 110, rect.Y + 5, rect.Width - 10, rect.Height - 10);
    }
}

private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Type colorType = typeof(System.Drawing.Color);
    PropertyInfo[] propInfoList = colorType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public);
    foreach (PropertyInfo c in propInfoList)
    {
        this.cmbboxClr.Items.Add(c.Name);
    }

}
```

Comment: What does the debugger tell you? Does the DrawItem ever get hit?  Are there any PropertyInfo  in the propInfoList  ? Do you perhaps overwrite the text with the fill color? You certainly leak a brush and a font..

Comment: The debugger shows me that the comboBox is being populated in the loop. But when I open the comboBox, it drops down like there are items but they are all blank. It looks like the correct number of items are there but no text, it's like they are all blank chars. I put a break point in the owner-drawn code and it did not stop, so that must be the problem. I'll look into that.

Comment: What is the `DrawMode` ?

Comment: OwnerDrawFixed is selected.

Comment: Then, unless you confuse the controls the even't may not be hooked up..?

Comment: I looked at some tutorials re owner-drawn controls but all they said was to make sure you set your control DrawMode to owner drawn and I did that. Is there another step I'm missing? My owner-drawn method never gets executed. That's why my comboBox is empty.

Comment: I missed adding this line:
comboBoxColorPicker.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(comboBoxColorPicker_DrawItem);
So now the owner drawn method fires and the color names (the text) show up in the combobox list...but the colors to the right of each item is missing!

Comment: Got it working...I needed to widen the comboBox so now I can see the color panels in their associated color. Thanks for the help!!